# Can IsotopeJS work without adding position: absolute to the Isotope items?

Tags: jquery-isotope

Isotope adds this style to the items:

```
position: absolute; 
left: 0px; 
top: 0px; 
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
```

Is it possible to disable this, but still keep Isotope functional? I have read about [`transformsEnabled`](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/options.html#transformsenabled) which says that disabling it will cause the browser to rely on top/left positioning. Can I do the reverse, so that the browser relies on CSS transformations, or does Isotope always rely on position: absolute?

Comment: Did you ever find any answer to this?

Comment: Nope. I think it is impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I agree that it seems impossible. For me, setting transformsEnabled to false allowed me to workaround my issue. But, that seems to be it.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, Isotope can work without adding position: absolute to the Isotope items. This is accomplished by defining styles with [hiddenStyle](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/options.html#hiddenstyle) and [visibleStyle](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/options.html#visiblestyle). This does seem to require some extra work once implemented, as can be seen at http://codepen.io/betweenbrain/pen/bkwuF . Hopefully that helps get you on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of unloaded images that causes the items overlap each other.
Try to initialize Isotope after all images have loaded by adding `imagesLoaded` function before call `isotop`. The code should look like this:

```
var $container = $('#container').imagesLoaded( function() {
   $container.isotope({
    // options
  });
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to download the imagesLoaded script and add it to the isotope.js file ;)

Answer (score 0):

Give the container width of 100% and position relative.